# How do I replace the battery on my Palm Zire 21?

Tags: battery, pda, palm-zire, palm

My Zire 21 PDA's battery won't hold a charge for more than a few minutes.  How do I replace it?

Comment: This is something of a "what's on topic?" test.  If you don't think the question is sufficiently "retro" (the Zire 21 was discontinued in 2005), please post in [this thread](http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-constitutes-retro).  If you don't think it's "computing" enough, please post in [this one](http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/47/what-constitutes-computing).

Comment: I had a Palm Tungsteng and I remember that I must to use a screwdriver for  the operation.

Answer (score 4):

iFixit has a (user-contributed) [guide on this subject](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Palm+Zire+21+Battery+Replacement/30033). The Zire battery appears to be a standard 3.7volt 600mAh Lithium-Ion unit, probably originating from cell phones. Amazon shows several non-OEM replacements available.